# Difference between ways of participating into BFC/IFC

Tags: html, css, layout, overflow

As far as I know, both `overflow: hidden` and `display: inline-block` establish a new BFC in `.mid-column`. However, the former would make `.mid-column` a block box, while the latter would make it an atomic inline-level boxes.

> Using `overflow: hidden`

```css
.left-column {
  float: left;
  background-color: grey;
}
.right-column {
  float: right;
  background-color: grey;
}
.mid-column {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-column">
    <h3>Left Column</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <h3>Right Column</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mid-column">
    <h3>Mid Column</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <div class="left-column">
      <h3>Inner Left Column</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
      <h3>Inner Right Column</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Using `display: inline-block`

```css
.left-column {
  float: left;
  background-color: grey;
}
.right-column {
  float: right;
  background-color: grey;
}
.mid-column {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-column">
    <h3>Left Column</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <h3>Right Column</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mid-column">
    <h3>Mid Column</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <div class="left-column">
      <h3>Inner Left Column</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
      <h3>Inner Right Column</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can only explain the layout in the first demo. According to the [document](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting)(bold mine):

> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the
>   left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right
>   edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a
>   box's line boxes may shrink due to the floats), **unless the box
>   establishes a new block formatting context** (in which case the box
>   itself [*may* become narrower](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#bfc-next-to-float) due to the floats).

The `overflow: hidden` rule establishes a new BFC, and [thus](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#bfc-next-to-float), the border box of `.mid-column` must not overlap the margin box of `.left-column` and `right-column`.

As for the second demo, the only thing I know is that there is an anonymous block box around `.mid-column`, which establishes an IFC for it. Unfortunately, I cannot explain it any further.

My question is: How does participating into an IFC, rather than a BFC, affect the layout? And it would be nice if somebody can provide an in-detail explanation on the second demo, or at least provide a link for the relevant document so I can figure it out.

Comment: The BFC's they create are the same. The way they participate in their BFCs and - in the latter case its IFC -  is quite different though.

Comment: @Alohci You mean the BFC created by `display: inline-block` is an IFC?

Comment: No. The IFC that the `display: inline-block` participates in. It may or may not establish an IFC, depending on what its contents are. On the basis of your example, it would not establish an IFC.

Comment: @Alohci I'm sorry but I can't understand this. Please help me clean it up: in my second demo, a BFC is created in `mid-column`, and where is the IFC? Is the IFC contained in `mid-column`, or it's containing `mid-column`? Also, what do you mean by "participates in"?

Comment: The IFC is established by the [anonymous block box](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level), inside the `.wrapper` div and outside the `.mid-column` div. I encourage you to read [section 9.4 of the CSS 2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#normal-flow) *very* carefully.

Comment: @Alohci I've read that really carefully, but I think in my second demo, `.mid-column` participates in a BFC, rather than an IFC, because "An inline formatting context is established by a block container box that contains no block-level boxes.", but `.left-column` and `.left-column` are "block-level boxes" contained by `.wrapper`.

Comment: That's why it's not the `.wrapper` div that establishes the IFC but the anonymous block box. The anonymous block box does not contain the `.left-column` and `.left-column` block level boxes.

Comment: @Alohci Oh, you're right……

Comment: @Alohci I understand now that in the first demo, `.mid-column` participates in a BFC which is established by `.wrapper`, while in the second demo, `.mid-column` participates in an IFC which is established by an anonymous block box. However, I'm still not sure what's the difference between the way they participate in their BFC/IFC. According to the specs, "However, floating boxes may come between the containing block edge and the line box edge.", so I think in my second demo, the left edge of `.mid-column` should be touching the right edge of `.left-column`.

Answer (score 2):

> How does participating into an IFC, rather than a BFC, affect the layout?

Inline-level boxes flow inline on line boxes, like text. That's all there is to it. The formatting context in which a box *participates* has no effect on any formatting context that the box may *establish* for its contents (if it establishes one).

`.mid-column` itself, when displayed as an inline-block, participates in an IFC that's established by an anonymous block box (created for this purpose), but as far as the descendants of `.mid-column` are concerned, they are participating in a BFC that's established by `.mid-column`. Whatever happens *outside* of this BFC is of no concern to them, and elements outside the BFC can never interfere with the block layout that's taking place in this BFC.

The anonymous block box that's generated around `.mid-column` in the second demo participates in the root BFC. `.wrapper` *does not establish a BFC* in either demo. Since the floats eat into the available width of `.wrapper` (and in turn the anonymous block box), there is not enough room for `.mid-column` to vertically align with the floats, and that is why `.mid-column` gets pushed down.

The relevant link has already been provided in the comments; section 9.4 of CSS2 tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: OK, now I understand that whether `.mid-column` itself participates into an IFC or a BFC does not affect the layout the content of `.mid-column`, but why `.mid-column` itself is inserted between two floating blocks in the first demo, while being "pushed down" in the second demo? I thought it should "flow inline like text", and thus behaves as it is in the first demo.

Comment: @sunqingyao: The entire box is seen as a single solid unit, like a single letter, which can't be broken apart. This is what atomic inline means. Since the box can't be broken apart, the only way to fit it without the floats getting in the way is to push it down.

Comment: Gotcha! I have another question: does anonymous block box really exist, or is just an imaginary assumption? According to the [document](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level): *To make it easier to define the formatting, we **assume** that there is an anonymous block box around "Some text".* The word "assume" smells fishy...

Comment: Haha, well you wouldn't be able to select them with CSS or inspect them in the browser, so your guess is as good as mine...

Comment: But considering table boxes have very specific layout rules, and anonymous table boxes appear very frequently in layouts with display: table/table-row/table-cell in order for elements with those display types to render properly, I'm pretty sure anonymous block boxes do actually exist, even if they're not selectable.

Comment: Thank you! Yet another question: Since the width of a inline block is **not** determined by its content( *The width of a line box is determined by a containing block and the presence of floats.* [ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#inline-formatting)), why can't it narrow itself so that it can fit into the space between two floating elements?

Comment: @sun qingyao: You misread. That's talking about a line box, not an inline-block.

Comment: I think the reason that the second inline-block is pushed down is because `anonymous block box` around `.mid-column` has `overflow:visible` which makes `anonymous block box` participate in the origin BFC. So,`anonymous block box` doesn't  establish new BFC and it is just a normal block box which is different from `.mid-column` with `overflow:hidden` in the first demo. We can prove that by add a parent div outside `.mid-column` and set the parent `overflow:hidden`. It will work like the first demo.

Comment: @xianshenglu: That's basically what I said in the second-to-last paragraph.